# WSO2 IS: Change HTTPS certificate

Tags: https, wso2, ssl-certificate

I am a total newbie in WSO2 configuration and a relative newbie in how HTTPS certificates work, so please bear with me.

I am trying to change the certificate for HTTPS connections in WSO2. Without any configuration WSO2 returns a certificate with the DN `CN = localhost,O = WSO2,L = Mountain View,ST = CA,C = US`. I am trying to change this with my own certificate, following the instructions from [this blog article](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/).

I have imported my certificate in the keystore and changed the config as described in the article. One notable difference is that I couldn't find `${carbon.home}/repository/conf/mgt-transports.xml`.

After doing this, connecting to the IS server management service results in the "localhost" certificate being returned, instead of the one imported.

The KeyStore and RegistryKeyStore entries in `repository/conf/carbon.xml`

```
   <KeyStore>                                                              
        <!-- Keystore file location-->                                      
        <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->                             
        <Type>JKS</Type>                                                    
        <!-- Keystore password-->                                           
        <Password>wso2carbon</Password>                                     
        <!-- Private Key alias-->                                           
        <KeyAlias>testcert</KeyAlias>                                       
        <!-- Private Key password-->                                        
        <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>                               
    </KeyStore>                                                             

     <!--                                                                   
        Encrypt Decrypt Store will be used for encrypting and decrypting       
    -->                                                                     
    <RegistryKeyStore>                                                      
        <!-- Keystore file location-->                                      
        <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->                             
        <Type>JKS</Type>                                                    
        <!-- Keystore password-->                                           
        <Password>wso2carbon</Password>                                     
        <!-- Private Key alias-->                                           
        <KeyAlias>testcert</KeyAlias>                                       
        <!-- Private Key password-->                                        
        <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>                               
    </RegistryKeyStore>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1: Create a new keystore with private and public key (key-pair).
Inside /repository/resources/security/ directory. The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) and truststore (client-truststore.jks) will be stored here.

•   Create a keystore containing a key-pair using java key tool (contained in the standard jdk) and save it as a jks file. The keystore contains THIS server’s key-pair (public & private keys).

•   The Keystore/Key-Pair should have the following properties/attributes :

```
KeystoreType = JKS,
KeyPairAlgorithm = RSA,
Size = 2048 bits
SignatureAlgorithm = SHA-256 WITH RSA
Password    (Must be exactly the same as the keystore password)
Name(Subject):  The CN(Common Name) of the key-pair should be the server’s hostname upon which the IS will be deployed (if you intend to use it as the key manager for api manager)
Extensions:
Key usage : Digital Signature , Key Encipherment , Data Encipherment , on Repudian
Subject Alternate name : IP address = IP address of this server
```

Step 2: Import the certificate chain from the keystore created in Step 1 into a truststore.

Create new trust store with same attributes

•   Export the certificate from the Keystore (step 1) into the truststore

Step 3: Change the configuration files as follows, reflecting the new keystore and truststore that have just been created.

Change the appropriate values in the following files (in /repository/conf/):

```
File                            Line number/s
identity.xml                    180
carbon.xml                      310
                                326
                                343
axis2/axis2_pt.xml              272
                                280
                                396
                                404
axis2/axis2.xml                 272
                                280
                                396
                                404
axis2/axis2_nhttp.xml           278
                                286
                                405
                                413
security/secret-conf.properties 21
                                30
sec.policy                      1
```

More or less , just search the files for "jks"

Delete the old keystores

Step4: Restart