# WSO2 ESB Secure Vault: Change Default KeyStore Password

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to modify the default wso2carbon.jks keystore password.

I've followed the secure vault configuration instructions here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Working+with+Passwords

However, this just encrypts your passwords with the default WSO2 keystore password, which probably isn't the most secure method of password encryption.

How do I change the default keystore password?

### What I've attempted so far:

I've attempted using the java keytool utility to modify the wso2carbon.jks file.

This code seems to quietly accept the store password change:

```
C:\Users> keytool –storepasswd –new MyNewPassword –keystore <WSO2 Home>\<ESB Home>\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks 
Enter keystore password: wso2carbon
```

I think try to set the password for the wso2carbon alias

```
C:\Users> keytool –keypasswd –alias wso2carbon –keystore <WSO2 Home>\<ESB Home>\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks 
Enter keystore password: wso2carbon
Enter key password for <wso2carbon>: wso2carbon
New key password for <wso2carbon>: myNewPassword
Re-enter new key password for <wso2carbon>: myNewPassword
```

But the next time I start up the ESB I get a lot of authentication errors.

I would appreciated it if somebody could provide me with some guidance on how to change this default password.

Comment: did you check ,changing the keystore password from carbon.xml https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Configuring+Keystores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, because I don't really understand what's going on in this JKS file, I'm just going to post how I solved the default password change issue. At least if you're not an encryption expert you can secure your passwords.

For the below code excerpts, I've used **WSO2 Home** and **ESB Home** to represent the path to generic WSO2 directories. For example,

WSO2 Home = C:\WSO2

ESB Home = [WSO2 Home]\wso2esb-4.9.0

1. Shut down your instance of WSO2 ESB if it's running
2. Change the keystore password of the JKS file packaged with WSO2. Use the default "wso2carbon" password to authenticate the password change request.

   ```
   C:\Users> keytool –storepasswd –new MyNewPassword –keystore <WSO2 Home>\<ESB Home>\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks 
   Enter keystore password: wso2carbon
   ```
3. Now that you've defined a new keystore password, you need to set the password for the wso2carbon alias which I believe resides within the JKS keystore.

   ```
   C:\Users> keytool –keypasswd –alias wso2carbon –keystore <WSO2 Home>\<ESB Home>\repository\resources\security\wso2carbon.jks 
   Enter keystore password: myNewPassword
   Enter key password for <wso2carbon>: myNewPassword
   New key password for <wso2carbon>: myNewPassword
   Re-enter new key password for <wso2carbon>: myNewPassword
   ```
4. Now you actually need to re-encrypt/encrypt your new password in the ESB Home directory. Go to **\respository\conf\security\cipher-text.properties** and edit the file. In my properties file I had already encrypted my passwords, but I just deleted the specific encrypted strings and replaced them with my new password inside **square brackets**. For example,

   ```
   #Thu Jan 14 15:03:03 EST 2016
   Carbon.Security.KeyStore.Password=[myNewPassword]
   Carbon.Security.KeyStore.KeyPassword=[myNewPassword]
   UserManager.AdminUser.Password=ads;fjahsdfhasdfsdfgag8a9fua9s8duf8a9sdufasfa{$%$3823l4kjfd89sud8f9usdf89gjq3489t89sfgj89werjq8394tj8r9gjrwegsfd{}#@$324028afdsauhui324jknjksdfsdfalj893489uasd89u23423|}Dfa908543
   Server.Service.Connector.keystorePass=[myNewPassword]
   Carbon.Security.TrustStore.Password=ads;fjahsdfhasdfsdfgag8a9fua9s8duf8a9sdufasfa{$%$3823l4kjfd89sud8f9usdf89gjq3489t89sfgj89werjq8394tj8r9gjrwegsfd{}#@$324028afdsauhui324jknjksdfsdfalj893489uasd89u23423|}Dfa908543
   Datasources.WSO2_CARBON_DB.Configuration.Password=3-asdfasdfhasdfsdfgag8a9fua9s8duf8a9sdufasfa{$%$3823l4kjfd89sud8f9usdf89gjq3489t89sfgj89werjq8394tj8r9gjrwegsfd{}#@$324028afdsauhui324jknjksdfsdfalj893489uasd89u23423|}Dfa908543+0=432432049234-23423
   ```
5. Then open up your command line and execute: `cd [ESB Home]\bin`
6. Now that you're in the bin directory of your ESB installation, run the command: 
    `ciphertool.bat -Dconfigure` 
    This will update the cipher-text.properties file and encrypt the plain text passwords.
7. Start up your ESB again, providing your new keystore password when prompted.

Comment: You should rather use a custom keystore. You changed the default ks + ts passwords, however the certificates inside are still signed with the old passwords. You don't need to be a security guru , see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253567/wso2-is-change-https-certificate/33259906#33259906 , I use keystore explorer for it http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/ , works well.

Comment: Hi @JavaMastaRSA , thanks for keystore-explorer utility tip! Just wondering, why should I use a custom keystore? Why isn't simply changing the default one's password sufficient?